# How to infer object key type based on another key in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I have a type with key-value pairs, where keys are React component names and values are the values they take as props. What I am trying to do is to type an array of types containing the type field, which is also the exact name of a component, and a `getter` and `setter` functions that use component values types.

```js
type ElementValues = {
    text: string,
    checkbox: boolean
}

type ElementType = keyof ElementValues

type Value<Type extends ElementType> = ElementValues[Type]

type Test = {
    [Type in ElementType]: {
    type: Type
    getter: () => Value<Type>
    setter: (value: Value<Type>) => any
}}[ElementType]

const testList: Array<Test> = [{
    type: 'checkbox',
    getter: () => 'test,
    setter: (value) => ({ })
}]
```

What I can get is the array with elements that do not care about the given component name and take all possible component value types as setter and getter params/return types.

In the above example, `getter` should require `boolean`, as for checkbox value, and `setter` should have a value type of `boolean`, not `boolean | string`.

Answer (score 1):

The following would do the trick. Just use [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions). This way the array elements are going to be discriminated by the `type` field (`text` or `checkbox`).

```js
type ElementValues = {
  text: string,
  checkbox: boolean
}

type ElementType = keyof ElementValues

type Value<Type extends ElementType> = ElementValues[Type]

type Test<Type extends ElementType> = {
  type: Type
  getter: () => Value<Type>
  setter: (value: Value<Type>) => any
}

// Here - Discriminated Unions
type Elements =
  | Test<'checkbox'>
  | Test<'text'>

const testList: Array<Elements> = [
  {
    type: 'text',
    getter: () => 'test1',
    setter: (value) => ({ })
  },
  {
    type: 'checkbox',
    getter: () => true,
    setter: (value) => ({ })
  }
]
```

Comment: How is this different to the [code in the question](https://tsplay.dev/W4PLeW)?

Comment: I've edited the answer to point exactly where the most important change is as a comment in the code itself.

Comment: I see that the code is a bit different. But the result looks to be exactly the same.

Comment: Oh, I see. It looks like I've just "deobfuscated" it a bit. OP had the answer all the time in his/her own question. (:

Comment: He probably is looking for something else, but has trouble telling us exactly what he wants.

Comment: What I was hoping to get was an generic type check for array elements based on ElementValues type, I don't want to type each combination of Test type in Elements type as those will finally be in greater count.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that adding helper type `Elements` solved the problem.
Based on [@lepsch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2828341/lepsch) answer:

```html
type ElementValues = {
  text: string,
  checkbox: boolean
}

type ElementType = keyof ElementValues

type Value<Type extends ElementType> = ElementValues[Type]

type Test<Type extends ElementType> = {
  type: Type
  getter: () => Value<Type>
  setter: (value: Value<Type>) => any
}

type Elements = {
    [Type in ElementType]: Test<Type>
}[ElementType]

const testList: Array<Elements> = [
  {
    type: 'text',
    getter: () => 'test',
    setter: (value) => ({ })
  },
  {
    type: 'checkbox',
    getter: () => true,
    setter: (value) => ({ })
  }
]
```